# How do enable Amazon Inspector on an Amazon Lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail, amazon-inspector

I am using AWS Lightsail instance, Is there any option to enable **Amazon Inspector** on the **Lightsail** environment?

Answer (score 0):

From AWS docs

Currently, Amazon Inspector assessment targets can consist only of EC2 instances. You can run an agentless assessment with the Network Reachability rules package on any EC2 instances regardless of operating system.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_supported_os_regions.html